# nice command behavior when only 1 function running

Tags: scheduling, nice

I just learned the existence of nice (and ionice) which seems to be really interesting.

I just want to launch a process 'p_low' with less priority than my ususal one 'p_normal'.

What I was able to get from the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)) (only source which shows me how the resource is distributed), is that:

> a process run with nice +15 will receive 25% of the CPU time allocated
>   to a normal-priority process: (20 − 15)/(20 − 0) = 0.25

So based on that I can provide 10% of the CPU time to my p_low process if "nice -18 p_low"

This is perfect **IF MY 'p_normal' IS RUNING**.

**So question: is there a way to tell the scheduler to use the default niceness value, and only -18 when there is something else running?**

In the worst case I can make a script which check if anything else is running, and "renice" my process, but it doesn't seem to be the best option to me...

---

EDIT:

**ANSWER:** 
As pointed out by @jilliagre in the comments below his answer:

> if nothing else is running the command will get 100% of the CPU
>   whatever the niceness given (-18, 0, +18, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing how nice works. It is simply a hint to the scheduler for it to prioritize some processes against others when there is a CPU bottleneck.

I there is nothing else running, whatever its niceness, your process will be granted all the CPU power so there is no need to change the niceness in that specific case.

Comment: @jilliagre, so I can basically simply launch my low priority script (p_low) with 'nice -18', right? -- if anything else run, it will allocate the full CPU power?

Comment: `nice -n -18` will make your process a high priority one, not low priority. Note that you'll need to be root to increase the priority. You probably want `nice -n 18 command ...` which will indeed leave more power to potential competing processes.

Comment: @jilliagre, running 'nice -n 18' === 'nice -18' based on this page: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/nice-renice-command-examples/  ...

Comment: so basically, if I run 'nice -18 COMMAND' (OR 'nice -n 18'), would it execute COMMAND with 100% of the CPU time if nothing else is running?

Comment: As already answered, if nothing else is running the command will get 100% of the CPU whatever the niceness given (-18, 0, +18, ...)

Comment: Yep, I just wanted to be sure... :) - thanks jilliagre

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, I didn't reply to your comment but you are correct, `nice -18` is indeed equivalent to `nice -n 18`. Raising the priority would have needed `nice --18`.